# How to run SpringBoot-based web app on Tomcat without showing port number?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have application in Spring Boot on localhost, url is: `127.0.0.1:8080`. Is it possible to omission port? I mean I want to write `127.0.0.1` and get this website.

Comment: where are you writing this 127.0.0.1? from browser. If it is browser than the default port is 80. You can make your  springboot run on this port and use the usrl without port

Answer (score 1):

In file `application.properties`, set

```
server.port=80
```

Then you can access web app at: `http://127.0.0.1`

**Reference:** http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port